# pandas insert a string and a list into the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I made this code that allows me to create a table in an excel file. Only I wanted to add at the beginning of the column a string and then afterwards attach a list of elements to it.

```
def CreateExcel(metric,consumo, writer):
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'metricID': metric,
        'consumo' : consumo,
    })
    df = df.sort_values('consumo', ascending=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="foglio1", startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["foglio1"]
    (max_row, max_col) = df.shape
    column_settings = [{"header":column} for column in df.columns]
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns":column_settings})
    worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 70)
```

this is the working code, but I would like to add a string like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'metricID': "timeframe" + metric,
        'consumo' : "2022-11-10 2022-12-10" + consumo,
    })
```

python does not give me a syntax error, but in running the code it gives me this error:

```
    'metricID': "timeframe" + metric,
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

keeping in mind that the elements in the list are sorted in the function later on, I need to have those two strings be at the beginning of the table, so that then they are not put randomly in the list

Comment: what is metric and consumo? A list of values?

Comment: if its a list: `['timeframe' + str(m) for m in metric]`. If its a number `'timeframe' + str(metric)`

Comment: I think he just wants to add a single string to the beginning of those lists, not manipulate each element within the list... but I am not sure about this

Comment: keeping in mind that the elements in the list are sorted in the function later on, I need to have those two strings be at the beginning of the table, so that then they are not put randomly in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'column':'string', 'column2':'string'}, index=[0])
df = pd.concat([new_row,df.loc[:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

so you can add rows to your table, if you insert them after sorting there will be no incompatibility errors

Answer (score 2):

We cannot reproduce without actual data, but I understand your question such that `consumo` and `metric` are lists that you want to extend by strings. So this is not a problem with pandas but a general one:

```
s = "hello"
l = ["world"]
result = [s] + l # concatenate the string (as a list) with an existing list
print(result)  # ["hello", "world"]
```

so the changes in your code are only subtle. Note that I added the list brackets to turn your string into a list.

```
def CreateExcel(metric,consumo, writer):
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'metricID': ["timeframe"] + metric,
        'consumo' : ["2022-11-10 2022-12-10"] + consumo,
    })
    df = df.sort_values('consumo', ascending=False)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="foglio1", startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets["foglio1"]
    (max_row, max_col) = df.shape
    column_settings = [{"header":column} for column in df.columns]
    worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns":column_settings})
    worksheet.set_column(0, max_col - 1, 70)
```

Comment: works fine, only now that string is reordered among the other values, which are float:  `df = df.sort_values('consumo', ascending=False)`

Comment: You want to use the strings as column titles, correct? Why don't you rename your columns instead of adding the title as the first row of your data?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to add an element to the front of metric and consumo (which I am assuming are list), you can go with this:

```
metric.insert(0, 'timeframe')

consumo.insert(0,"2022-11-10 2022-12-10")
```

If you want to join "timeframe" and "2022-11-10 2022-12-10" as strings to each and every element in those lists, go with the below approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'metricID': [metric_string+ x for x in metric],
        'consumo' : [consumo_string+ x for x in consumo]
    })
```